# rubocop "undefined method" for everything

Tags: ruby, vim, chef-infra, chef-recipe, rubocop

I'm using rubocop with syntastic to write Chef code.

Something weird happens where after I satisfy all of rubocop's suggestions it flags every function call "undefined".

For example here it is flagging an extra space (this is a Chef resource I am writing):
[image]

OK so I remove the extra space and run a syntax check and then it flags everything as undefined:
[image]

Why is it doing this and how can I stop this behavior?

Comment: If your `.rb` file is not properly self-contained, as in it depends on a number of things being loaded before you can run it in isolation, you might get errors like this. Is there any way to tell Rubocop to load in particular modules first?

Comment: Can I just skip this check for now? Otherwise I'm assuming I'd have to hook it up to a tags file right?

Comment: Syntastic has a `foodcritic` checker for `chef`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to disable that Rubocop rule. Chef uses a DSL, meaning there are methods that are magically injected into the context which Rubocop can't know about.